# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Everytime I create a new flutter project and tried to run it on virtual device, I always get this error message

> Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.

The solution I did is update the build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties from

**build.grade**

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

To

**build.grade**

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip

Since I'm just learning flutter, it's annoying that everytime I create a new project to learn I have to change those version.

Is there a way to set it up automatically new project? Or to support the newest version of gradle for new flutter project?

Answer (score 1):

I too was experiencing this error, but only when building my flutter project from a USB drive (formatted as exFAT) connected to a Win10 system. Once I copied the project to my main drive (NTFS) and ran from there, it worked ok with the flutter gradle defaults.