# Problems after upgrading Android Build Tools,

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex, android-jetifier

I have upgraded my Android Studio to version 2020.3.1 Patch 2 and along with that I have upgraded buildTools to 30.0.3. My ndk version is 23.0.7599858 and my JDK is OpenJDK 11. My minSdk is 27, compile and target Sdk are at 30.

Previously, before upgrading, builds were running fine. Now, when I change any Gradle file and hit "Sync Now", it appears to be still working (telling me that the build was successful). However, when I debug or run my application via the ADB on my real device, the build process stops at

> Task :app:packageQaDebug FAILED

With the reason

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageQaDebug' (type 'PackageApplication').
>
> - Type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication' property 'appMetadata' specifies file [..] which doesn't exist

I have tried to run the gradle build from the command line with gradlew.bat, both with
`--stacktrace` and `--show-warnings all` enabled, but the messages do not get any more verbose (except that I get a stack trace in the former case, which points to some exception in the inner workings of Gradle).

I have tried enabling/disabling

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

with no result. I have read that sometimes the issue might be caused by to small Xmx setting, so I increased it in my gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Still nothing. I also upgraded all dependencies I could, but still, same error.

As I have spend several hours with this issue, not being able to help myself, I would be thankful for any hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a solution to this, based on the post on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28954. I have also deleted the .gradle folder, this made the build run again.

Comment: Plus as stated here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457352/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appcompressdebugassets) it appears as if certain file systems affect the issue as well.